# show paginate according to data in relation table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I'm going to create blog in Laravel. Now I get post form category in the blog and I can only show paginate according to post but I want to show paginate only for posts that have relations with category id

I have some problem in my code, please help me to fix my problem.

In the controller source code:

```
//this code show posts according to category id
$postCatId = $request->postCatId;
$postList =PostCat::with("posts")->where('id',$postCatId)->get();

//this code show paginate according to posts has relation with category
$paginate=PostCat::with("posts")->where('id',$postCatId)->paginate(2);
```

This then returns `$postList` and `$paginate` to view

in View:

```
//show posts has relation with category id
@foreach($PostList as $post)
     @foreach($post->posts as $post_item)
     {{$post_item->id}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach


//show paginate according to posts has relation with category id
{{$paginate->links()}}
```

But I cannot show paginate with posts that has relation with category id

Comment: You want to paginate all posts which have a category? Because now you're paginating categories, but not posts.

Comment: exactly ,with this code only paginate for category but i wants to show paginate according to posts has relational with category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to paginate posts that have a category, use this query instead of two current ones:

```
$posts = Post::with('category')
             ->has('category')
             ->where('id', $postCatId)
             ->paginate(2);
```

Make sure you have `category()` relationship in the `Post` model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PostCat');
}
```

In a view iterate over `$posts` and render links:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div>Post ID is {{ $post->id }} and category ID is {{ $post->category->id }}</div>
@endforeach

{{ $paginate->render() }}
```

Comment: no, i think its wrong becuase this code:

$posts = Post::with('category')
             ->has('category')
             ->where('id', $postCatId)
             ->paginate(2);
only show category paginate

Comment: No, this code fetches all posts which have a category and ignores posts without a category. Then it's paginating results (paginating posts).

Answer (score 0):

The easier way for many to many relationship in Laravel 5 and paginate this:

Category Model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

Article Model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

When you want to download all the posts/articles from the category with the pagination:

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$category_articles = $category->articles()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```